# Catch on JS Promise being called but not calling other jest mocked object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, mocking, jestjs

I have a simple js function that tries to connect to mongodb via a Promise and either succeeds of fails.

```
const MongodbService = () => {
  mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl, options).then(() => {
    logger.info('Mongodb Connected', { url: process.env.MONGODB_URL })
  }).catch(err => {
    logger.error('Mongodb: ${err}', { url: process.env.MONGODB_URL })
  })

  return mongoose
}
```

and I want to simply test it. I mock the logger:

```
import logger from '../../../config/winston'
jest.mock('../../../config/winston')
```

I have spec for testing success, which works as expected:

```
it('it should handle a connection success', async () => {
  mongoose.connect = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
  await MongodbService()
  expect(logger.info.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('Mongodb Connected')
  expect(logger.info.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual({ url: 'mongodb://mongodb/jb-dev' })
})
```

I have another which check for failure, and this is where I'm stuck:

```
it('it should handle a connection failure', async () => {
  mongoose.connect = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error('boom')))
  await MongodbService()
  expect(logger.error.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('Mongodb Error: boom')
})
```

This is failing stating the logger has not been called, even though when I put a console.log in the function I can see it has correctly been called. If I add a setTimeout around the expect I can then see the logger being called, but it's been called twice. I think I'm missing something simple. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! So I was miss-understanding the information returned when I thought it was not working. Adding nextTick worked for me just fine:

```
it('it should handle a connection failure', async () => {
  mongoose.connect = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error('bang')))
  await MongodbService()
  process.nextTick(() => {
    expect(logger.error.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('Mongodb: Error: bang')
  })
})
```